# What is a word or phrase for when someone's statement reveals their ignorance in something?

Tags: meaning

It's not a lie or a joke, it's when the speaker doesn't know that by saying what they said other people can figure out they don't know something.

For example:

> "Dolphins are my favorite kind of fish."

This reveals the speaker does not know that dolphins are actually mammals, but would suggest they probably know very little about fish, mammals, or even animals in general.

Instead of having to say, "You just said something that reveals to me that you are ignorant in something", I would want to say, "You just committed a _____".

I always want to say you "jumped the shark" in your statement, or you committed a "faux pas", but those aren't correct.

Comment: Not quite what you’re looking for, but reminds me of the expression, “*Better to be thought a fool than to open your mouth and remove all doubt.*”

Answer (score 1):

OPTIONS:

[howler](https://www.google.com/search?q=faux%20pas%20definition&oq=faux%20pas&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4409j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=howler)

> a stupid or glaring mistake, especially an amusing one.

[gaffe](https://www.google.com/search?q=faux%20pas%20definition&oq=faux%20pas&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4409j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=gaffe)

> an unintentional act or remark causing embarrassment to its originator; a blunder.

[blunder](https://www.google.com/search?q=faux%20pas%20definition&oq=faux%20pas&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4409j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=blunder)

> a stupid or careless mistake.

[flub](https://www.google.com/search?q=faux%20pas%20definition&oq=faux%20pas&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4409j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=flub)

> a thing badly or clumsily done; a blunder.

Comment: Those are pretty good, though they don't really get to the "now I know what you don't know" point I'm looking for. Maybe a word or two could be added to one of those to complete the full intention?

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with for you. I would also have to say I agree with Lisa that something like "You just committed an ignorant mistake." is very appropriate.

Comment: You see, the "now I'm aware of just how stupid you are.....", logic (which seems to be what you want - but you want a direct way to say it) is implied. Because if you said this to them then you know they are wrong, you know they are ignorant, committed a massive blunder, or a flub, and it's implied that you both know just how limited their knowledge is on that subject. Unless it really was just a small mistake. That will only be known from the context of the conversation and the size of the mistake.

Comment: I agree with Kace that "blunder" is frequently understood to be more than merely a mistake but an expression of truly having no clue or a false impression.(although sometimes it can still mean a careless mistake - but usually one that gives the impression that you don't have a clue)  A flub is frequently poorly executing something you were capable of doing better (an champion quality gymnast can flub a vault) - a gaffe is often a breach not thinking about what you're saying...a bit of thought would have saved you ... and most often everyone knows it was a gaffe.

Answer (score 0):

I would say : "You just committed an **incongruity**"
 **:** - the quality of disagreeing; being unsuitable and inappropriate.
             http://www.thefreedictionary.com/incongruity
 → She smiled at the incongruity of the question.